# How would i look through a dictionary and see if a word in the user input is a value and print the key

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, for-loop

I have made a dictionary from a text document, the key for the dictionary is the solution and i need help iterating through the values to see if it contains a word from te question and print the key (the solution).
My code is below

```
dic = {}
with open("keywords.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
            line = line.strip().split(",")
            dic[line[0]] = line[1:]
print (dic)

question = (input("What is your problem?: "))
```

for key, values in dic:

Comment: `for key, value in dic.items(): if value == value_to_find: print(key)`

Comment: This gives me this error                                                                                    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\other\Documents\New folder\New Text Document.py", line 11, in <module>
    if value == value_to_find:
NameError: name 'value_to_find' is not defined

Comment: You haven't defined `value_to_find`, this variable represents what you are looking for.